# Same function tag for two languages

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't know how exactly i should ask this question. But this is the scenario.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570676/pluck-with-where-condition) .

I have used a tag called 'pluck' for my question. But after a user commented on it, i found that the tag refers to 'rails' but not 'laravel'.

I could not find a separate tag for laravel pluck. What should i do now?

Should i remove the tag because it is referring another language? But I feel that particular tag suits the question (Because tagging just 'laravel' make less sense).

What should I do now?

Comment: I can see 29 questions tagged for 'pluck' including mine. And a lot of questions in first page of that 29 questions have tagged 'laravel' along with it. So, i feel nothing wrong being part of them :)

Comment: In my opinion, functions shouldn't have a tag at all

Comment: Agreed.  Lets pluck it from the tag list

Comment: Your title mentions pluck, and you have it in the body of your question. People interested in pluck and laravel can easily find your question. So what should you do now? Nothing.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan but i have tagged an another language's tag. So if any of rail user filtering the question using pluck, he may get confused whether the question is laravel's or rail's. Anyhow I have tagged 'laravel' also along with it, so they may clear. But still i just wanted to know my tag is correct one or not.

Comment: And I'm saying you should not have the `pluck` tag on your question because it refers to a different language, and is unnecessary for your question.